# MATLAB code break

Tags: matlab, break

I have started running a script on MATLAB that takes days to finish. Usually, if I changed my mind and I don't want wait for it to finish and I get content with the intermediate results, I highlight the command window and press Ctrl-C to break the code.

Now, I have run MATLAB. But its desktop got kinda stuck in the background. When I try to restore the desktop from the toolbar, it does not restore. But I know from the task manager that the process is running and is consuming Memory and CPU performance. So, I am kinda stuck. I don't want to kill the process because I need the intermediate values in the workspace, and I can't open the desktop to break the code using ctrl-c.

Is there any solution? For example, is there any command that can be used in the command prompt to act as ctrl-c for MATLAB?

I am using MATLAB R2012b and Windows 8.

Comment: Pretty sure there's nothing you can do, but there's definitely nothing you can do with _cmd_ that would work.

Comment: You can use the `pause` command in your code in the future to improve the odds of it becoming responsive.  A 1-10 second pause every so often may be enough to get it to come back.

Answer (score 0):

Quick try to fix the recent Problem:

- Try ty set a higher priority to matlab.exe in the Task Manager. (Right click -> Priority -> Higher than normal). Then see if you can get the window to front.

Some approaches to avoid this problem in future:

- Try to optimize your code. For starters look at: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html
- Use Matlab compiler for faster execution: http://de.mathworks.com/products/compiler/
- Include some `drawnow` commands at stratetic positions in the code. This allows matlab to process the Event Queue and capture ctr-C commands.
- Save intermediate results to output files. For example you could write an output file all 30 min with your intermediate results. Easyiest way would be just `save(filename)`. Then a `.mat`file with all your workspace variables is generated. You can than kill the process in the task manager, without loosing too much results.